# CCleaner found thousands of duplicate system-related files. What do I do with them?

Tags: duplicate

[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) found thousands of duplicate files.  There are many different names, it looks like mostly DLLs and themes, that are scattered all over the computer.  Their size varies anywhere from .8kb and 60kb. Names are things like `theme.cfg`,  `NVprxy64.dll` and really anything else.

Should I get rid of them? If so, how, and if not, why? I’m not really sure what I need to do with them or what they mean but it seems like they are taking up a lot of space.

Comment: Well where are they, what's the name, and how big are they?

Comment: They look to be in MS Office, Nvidia drivers, and basically all over my PC. Their size varies anywhere from .8kb and 60kb.  Names are things like theme.cfg (so I guess they're not all DLLs) "NVprxy64.dll" and really anything else.  They're all just duplicates of one another sitting around. I'm worried it will damage something if I clear them.

Comment: Did you install Windows more than once? Some of them might be in the backup directory. With some installations, the .DLL files would have been placed into the program directory and then copied into the Windows/System directory. It is also possible that Ccleaner looked inside .cab and .zip files and discovered the duplicates. You need to look at the directory where they reside and determine how the files were placed there before you delete anything.

Answer (score 3):

> I’m not really sure what I need to do with them or what they mean but
>   it seems like they are taking up alot of data.

A lot of individual files? Or are all of these files small and inconsequential? The reality is your efforts to clean up a filesystem like this might provide you with *slightly* more disk space, but in the end might leave you with an overall unstable system where some programs/functions could just fail if those DLLs are removed. In fact a quick Google search for “[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)” and “DLL” shows *a lot of folks* with various DLL issues that may or may not have been caused by “overeager” use of CCleaner.

My advice is that unless this exercise gives you a *truly amazing* benefit in cleaning up space, it’s best to leave your system alone. The risk of damage caused by doing a “slash and burn” cleanup on unknown files might just not be worth it. It’s *always* best to err on the side of being conservative/stable. You’re much better off investing in a newer, larger hard drive—since they are relatively cheap nowadays—and just transferring your system to that new hard drive if you need more space.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah it seems like there might be maybe a gig or less and slash and burn does seem like a bad idea.

Comment: +1 for both Q&A, as the asking gives the opportunity for the sensible answer.